# How to show that ab and c are coprime when $(a,c)=(b,c)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-zero integers. Suppose $a$ and $c$ are coprime. And suppose $b$ and $c$ are coprime. How can I then show that $ab$ and $c$ are coprime?

From what I know so far this means $ra + sc = 1$ (since a and c are coprime)
Likewise: $tb + uc = 1$

If $ab$ and $c$ are coprime it follows: $v(ab) + pc = 1$

Beyond that I am rather stuck- I have tried rearranging in terms of $a$ and $b$ but with no success

Comment: I would tackle the contrapositive.  If $ab$ and $c$ are not coprime, they share a prime factor $p \gt 1$.  Now use the defining property of a prime on $ab$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $ab$ and $c$ were not coprime.  Then there must be some prime number $p$ that divides both $ab$ and $c$.  (*Be sure to understand why*).

But since $p$ is prime and $p\mid ab$ that implies that $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

In the first case, we have then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid c$ contradicting that $\gcd(a,c)=1$, and in the second case we have $p\mid b$ and $p\mid c$ contradicting that $\gcd(b,c)=1$.

Comment: Why does there have to be a prime number that divides both $ab$ and $c$? I mean why is it necessarily a prime number? I am trying to understand using the co-primality of $a$ & $c$ and $b$ & $c$ respectively, but can't see how this is required

Comment: @Questioner Two numbers $x$ and $y$ are coprime if and only if $\gcd(x,y)=1$ if and only if there is no prime $p$ that simultaneously divides both $x$ and $y$.  The first iff statement is by definition.  The second iff statement can be proven.  In the one direction, supposing there was such a $p$ that divided both, then $\gcd(x,y)\neq 1$ since $p$ is a larger common divisor than $1$ is implying $1$ could not be the *greatest* common divisor.  In the other direction, supposing that $\gcd(x,y)=g\neq 1$ then by F.T.A. $g$ can be written as a product of primes.  Let $p$ be one such prime.  Q.E.D.

Comment: Negating each, we get $x$ and $y$ are not coprime if and only if $\gcd(x,y)\neq 1$ if and only if there exists some prime $p$ such that $p\mid x$ and $p\mid y$ simultaneously.  It is certainly possible that some composite number divides both, but if a composite number divides both then one of the primes that make up that composite number also divides both.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If $ab$ and $c$ are not coprime, there is a $d$ which divides both $ab$ and $c$. Thus, there exists a *prime* p that divides both $ab$ and $c$ (either $d$ is prime and then $p=d$ or $d$ is not prime and take any one of its prime factors).

Since $p|(ab)$, either $p|a$ or $p|b$. Can you finish this reaching the contradiction?

Comment: You left out an important qualification on divisor $d$.

Comment: $4$ divides $(6\cdot 2)$ but $4$ does not divide $6$, nor does it divide $2$.  We need primality to make such a claim

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you very much, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a prime $p$ that divide $c$ and $ab$. But then $p$ divide also $a$ or $b$. So if $p$ divide $a$ then $p$ divide $a$ and $c$. A contradiction.
The same contradiction we get if $p$ divide $b$.